# Inserting a record that references records from other tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

This is a fairly basic question, but I was quite surprised not to find a decent answer anywhere.

Consider the following database schema:

```
Person {PersionID, Name, CountryOfBirthID [references Country]}
Country {CountryID, CountryName}
```

The application reads all the countries from the database during the startup and keeps them in a list.
Whenever I'm adding a new person, I'm creating a new Country object with ID and data from the list mentioned above. I'm expecting EF to insert a new Person with the ID referencing a record in Country table, but it inserts a new record to Country table and assigns it a new ID, which is obviously not what I want.

What is the conventional way of inserting a new record that references records in other tables?
I assume, I can fetch a Country record by ID whenever I am adding a Persion (under the same context) and reuse a fetched record, but is there some other way that would allow me to access only Person table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you need to `'Attach'` your `Country` first (i.e, letting Entity Framwork knows that's it's already exists in the context/database):

```
 var person = new Person { ... };
 var country = new Country { Id = ... } // or _countriesList[2] in your case;
 person.Country = country;

 context.Attach(country);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Also, if you created your entities using the Designer in Visual Studio, your entities should contain a property named `'EntityReference'` which you can use to achieve the same result:

```
var person = new Person {};
person.Country.EntityReference = new EntityKey("MyEntities.Countries", "CountryId", countryId);
```

(Replace 'MyEntities.Countries' and 'CountryId' with the appropriate values)

Yet, i believe the easiest way is to 'expose' the foreign key in your entity:

```
class Person
{
  ....
  Country CountryOfBirth { get; set; }
  int CountryOfBirthID { get; set; } 
}

//then:

var person = new Person { ... };
person.CountryOfBirthId = 2;
```

If you're looking for a more generic way to handle this, look for the `Identity Map` pattern.